# Pagination localization best practices?

Tags: pagination

How would one design pagination intended for localization of many languages?

### Current approach

With my current approach I’m trying to be supersave, thus providing labeled buttons for previous and next with the arrows like so

```
< prev. page     1 2 3 ... 8     next page >
```

on mobile though because of the lack of space it looks like

```
< prev    page 1 of 8   next >
```

---

### The issue

Do other languages has shortened conventions like **prev** and **next**? I know some have for sure, e.g. russian is **пред** / **след**.

---

### Possible solution

One of solutions would be is to remove labels altogether, which some big players seem to do (e.g. Airbnb only has arrows like)

```
< page 1 of 8 >
```

---

But are there better solutions? Or are arrows enough and users are used to them so labels are obsolete now?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you can remove labels or not will depend on your core users. If you're dealing with a diverse crowd you may not be able to get away with removing signifiers. Signifiers, like labels, increase usability.

I would stay away from designing with abbreviations in mind. Some users might not understand your intentions, and not all languages support it. For example, you can't shorten "Next" or "Previous" in Dutch.

You should test whether or not just using arrows works for your users.